# xkcd package: "Ignoring Unknown Aesthetics"

Tags: r

I am following the example in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xkcd/vignettes/xkcd-intro.pdf) on pp. 7-8 (under "Some Basic Examples.")

Here is the code:

```
library(xkcd)
volunteers <- data.frame(year=c(2007:2011),
                           number=c(56470, 56998, 59686, 61783, 64251))
 xrange <- range(volunteers$year)
 yrange <- range(volunteers$number)
 ratioxy <- diff(xrange) / diff(yrange)
datalines <- data.frame(xbegin=c(2008.3,2010.5),ybegin=c(63000,59600),
                           xend=c(2008.5,2010.3), yend=c(63400,59000))
mapping <- aes(
  x = x, y = y, scale = scale, ratioxy = ratioxy, angleofspine = angleofspine, 
  anglerighthumerus = anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus = anglelefthumerus,
  anglerightradius = anglerightradius, angleleftradius = angleleftradius,
  anglerightleg =  anglerightleg, angleleftleg = angleleftleg, 
  angleofneck = angleofneck)
dataman <- data.frame( x= c(2008,2010), y=c(63000, 58850),
                          scale = 1000 ,
                          ratioxy = ratioxy,
                          angleofspine = -pi/2 ,
                          anglerighthumerus = c(-pi/6, -pi/6),
                          anglelefthumerus = c(-pi/2 - pi/6, -pi/2 - pi/6),
                          anglerightradius = c(pi/5, -pi/5),
                          angleleftradius = c(pi/5, -pi/5),
                          angleleftleg = 3*pi/2 + pi / 12 ,
                          anglerightleg = 3*pi/2 - pi / 12,
                          angleofneck = runif(1, 3*pi/2-pi/10, 3*pi/2+pi/10))
p <- ggplot() + geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=year, y =number),
                               data =volunteers, method="loess") +
   xkcdaxis(xrange,yrange) +
  ylab("Volunteers at Caritas Spain") +
   xkcdman(mapping, dataman) +
 annotate("text", x=2008.7, y = 63700,
             label = "We Need\nVolunteers!", family="xkcd" ) +
  annotate("text", x=2010.5, y = 60000,
             label = "Sure\nI can!", family="xkcd" ) +
   xkcdline(aes(xbegin=xbegin,ybegin=ybegin,xend=xend,yend=yend),
             datalines, xjitteramount = 0.12)

Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, diameter
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, diameter
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, diameter
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, diameter
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: scale, ratioxy, angleofspine, anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus, anglerightradius, angleleftradius, anglerightleg, angleleftleg, angleofneck, xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xbegin, ybegin, xend, yend
```

As we can see, a ton of warnings appear. Digging into the various functions didn't offer much insight; my only guess is that `ggplot2` doesn't know how to handle these various aesthetics. Why are these warnings appearing, and is it a problem?

Session Info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xkcd_0.0.5     extrafont_0.17 ggplot2_2.2.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9         RColorBrewer_1.1-2  plyr_1.8.4         
 [4] base64enc_0.1-3     tools_3.3.1         rpart_4.1-10       
 [7] digest_0.6.12       tibble_1.2          gtable_0.2.0       
[10] htmlTable_1.9       checkmate_1.8.2     lattice_0.20-33    
[13] Matrix_1.2-6        gridExtra_2.2.1     Rttf2pt1_1.3.4     
[16] stringr_1.2.0       cluster_2.0.4       knitr_1.15.1       
[19] htmlwidgets_0.8     grid_3.3.1          nnet_7.3-12        
[22] data.table_1.10.4   survival_2.41-2     foreign_0.8-66     
[25] latticeExtra_0.6-28 Formula_1.2-1       extrafontdb_1.0    
[28] magrittr_1.5        Hmisc_4.0-2         scales_0.4.1       
[31] backports_1.0.5     htmltools_0.3.5     splines_3.3.1      
[34] assertthat_0.1      colorspace_1.3-2    labeling_0.3       
[37] stringi_1.1.2       acepack_1.4.1       lazyeval_0.2.0     
[40] munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: It's based on an older version of `ggplot2`. It needs to be updated. If I have time I'll try to do so.

Comment: What is it that you want? What is the expected output?

Comment: I will also edit the question to separate the code and the warning part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are harmless, if a little annoying. To remove them, the `xkcdline.R` source needs to be edited so that the extra aesthetics are removed from the mapping before being passed to `geom_path()`. From the 0.05 version, the following changes need to be made to `xkcdline.R`:

New internal function:

```
remove_xkcd_mappings <- function(mapping) {
  mapping <- mapping[!(names(mapping) %in% c("xbegin",
                                             "xend",
                                             "ybegin",
                                             "yend",
                                             "diameter",
                                             "scale",
                                             "ratioxy",
                                             "angleofspine",
                                             "anglerighthumerus",
                                             "anglelefthumerus",
                                             "anglerightradius",
                                             "angleleftradius",
                                             "anglerightleg",
                                             "angleleftleg",                            
                                             "angleofneck"))]
}
```

Change to end of `xkcdline` function:

```
  listofpaths <- lapply(listofinterpolateswithillustrativedata,
                        function(x, mapping, mask, ...) {
                          pathmask <- NULL
                          ##print(mapping)
                          if(mask) {
                            ## Plot a white line widther that the original line
                            ## We must check the color, colour or size
                            ## and change them to white and a greater width
                            argList<-list(...)

                            for(i in intersect(c("color","colour"), names(argList)))
                              argList[i] <- NULL
                            argList$mapping <- remove_xkcd_mappings(mapping)
                            argList$data <- x
                            argList$colour <- "white"
                            if(is.null(argList$size)==TRUE) argList$size <- 3
                            if(argList$size <= 3 ) argList$size <- 3
                            else  argList$size <- argList$size *2
                            ##print(argList)
                            pathmask <- do.call("geom_path",argList)
                            ##pathmask <- geom_path(mapping = mapping, data = x, colour="white",size=8)
                            }
                          c(pathmask,
                            geom_path(mapping = remove_xkcd_mappings(mapping), data = x, ...))
                       },
                       mapping = mapping,
                       mask= mask 
                        ## mask = mask,
                        ## ... = ... ggplot2.0 does not like dots
                       )
  listofpaths
```

I've put a version of `xkcd` up at [github](https://github.com/NikNakk/xkcd). This could be installed by using `devtools::install_github("NikNakk/xkcd")`.

There are still warnings that relate to the use of `loess` on this dataset, but these have nothing to do with `xkcd`. This can be seen by plotting the following:

```
ggplot() + geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = year, y = number),
                            data = volunteers, method = "loess")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Two things: it should be `install_github()` instead of `install()`, and although that error is resolved, when I run `p` on its own after it is declared, I get these errors: `1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
  span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.` and similarly with `pseudoinverse used at 2007`, `neighborhood radius 2.02`, `reciprocal condition number  0`, `There are other near singularities as well. 4.0804` as the second lines of the errors...

Comment: ... and then they repeat with `In predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata)) as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)),  :` as the first-lined errors.

Comment: I've put my `sessionInfo()` in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I re-ran your code and it gave a pretty good result (I am hoping that is what you are expecting).

**First of all**, update all the associated packages, **ggplot2, extrafont, xkcdcolors, xkcd, etc.**

I just added some extra libraries and a last line to the code that you provided and it worked like a charm,

the code is as follows:

```
library(xkcd)
library(xkcdcolors)
library(extrafont)
volunteers <- data.frame(year=c(2007:2011),
                         number=c(56470, 56998, 59686, 61783, 64251))
xrange <- range(volunteers$year)
yrange <- range(volunteers$number)
ratioxy <- diff(xrange) / diff(yrange)
datalines <- data.frame(xbegin=c(2008.3,2010.5),ybegin=c(63000,59600),
                        xend=c(2008.5,2010.3), yend=c(63400,59000))
mapping <- aes(
  x = x, y = y, scale = scale, ratioxy = ratioxy, angleofspine = angleofspine, 
  anglerighthumerus = anglerighthumerus, anglelefthumerus = anglelefthumerus,
  anglerightradius = anglerightradius, angleleftradius = angleleftradius,
  anglerightleg =  anglerightleg, angleleftleg = angleleftleg, 
  angleofneck = angleofneck)
dataman <- data.frame( x= c(2008,2010), y=c(63000, 58850),
                       scale = 1000 ,
                       ratioxy = ratioxy,
                       angleofspine = -pi/2 ,
                       anglerighthumerus = c(-pi/6, -pi/6),
                       anglelefthumerus = c(-pi/2 - pi/6, -pi/2 - pi/6),
                       anglerightradius = c(pi/5, -pi/5),
                       angleleftradius = c(pi/5, -pi/5),
                       angleleftleg = 3*pi/2 + pi / 12 ,
                       anglerightleg = 3*pi/2 - pi / 12,
                       angleofneck = runif(1, 3*pi/2-pi/10, 3*pi/2+pi/10))
p <- ggplot() + geom_smooth(mapping=aes(x=year, y =number),
                            data =volunteers, method="loess") +
  xkcdaxis(xrange,yrange) +
  ylab("Volunteers at Caritas Spain") +
  xkcdman(mapping, dataman) +
  annotate("text", x=2008.7, y = 63700,
           label = "We Need\nVolunteers!", family="xkcd" ) +
  annotate("text", x=2010.5, y = 60000,
           label = "Sure\nI can!", family="xkcd" ) +
  xkcdline(aes(xbegin=xbegin,ybegin=ybegin,xend=xend,yend=yend),
           datalines, xjitteramount = 0.12)
p
```

There was however a *warning* about *xkcd-fonts* being missing, the warning looked like : 
`Warning message:In theme_xkcd() : Not xkcd fonts installed! See vignette("xkcd-intro")`. I ignored it and after the last line `p`, I got the following output,

[image]

This is I guess what you wanted.

To handle the warning, please refer [Section 2 | xkcd-vignettes | Journal of Statistical Software | Section 2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xkcd/vignettes/xkcd-intro.pdf).

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, not working:1: In simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree = degree, parametric = parametric,  :
  span too small.   fewer data values than degrees of freedom.....9: In predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata)) as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)),  :
  reciprocal condition number  0
10: In predLoess(object$y, object$x, newx = if (is.null(newdata)) object$x else if (is.data.frame(newdata)) as.matrix(model.frame(delete.response(terms(object)),  :
  There are other near singularities as well. 4.0804